# Include more than one media attribute in phtml

Tags: magento2, attributes, media-images

I want to add multiple media image attributes in my phtml template but if I use more than one then none of them show :(

I'm using the following:

```
$product = $block->getProduct();

$productImageAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute( 'custom_image_1' );
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
    ->init($product, 'custom_image_1')
    ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());
```

and then I can include it as follows:

```
<img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getTitle()); ?>"  />
```

If I want to add another I would assume that I need to do this:

```
$productImageAttr2 = $product->getCustomAttribute( 'custom_image_2' );
$productImage2 = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
    ->init($product, 'custom_image_2')
    ->setImageFile($productImageAttr2->getValue());
```

but when I do, neither images show.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Where are you trying to get these attributes

Comment: I've created a custom ptml which I am including via XML on the product page

Comment: have you created attributes through admin?

Comment: Yes :) I can get one attribute to show but if I try to include another one then neither show

Comment: check if you have enabled "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" and
"Used in Product Listing" in storefront properties tab.

Comment: Also you can manually make image tag if you are getting url in  $productImageAttr2 = $product->getCustomAttribute( 'custom_image_2' );

Comment: Yes those settings are applied. As mentioned, I can get custom_image_1 to show but as soon as I include the code for custom_image_2 neither images show

Comment: echo $productImageAttr2 and  $productImageAttr1 to see if you are getting both their values. I think the problem is with $productImage2  and $productImage1.

Comment: `<?php echo $productImageAttr ?>` didn't display anything :(

Comment: you might want to var_dump($productImageAttr)

Comment: That was a great help thank you. I've found that the problem is with the `$productImage` variable. When using `productImage2` it is returning the same values as `$productImage`. Do you know how I can solve this please?